# Could not make Xammp hosted local website work over VPN

Tags: xampp, vpn, windows-7-x64

We have been using Xampp at local Windows 7 system for quite sometime and now intend to share its VPN access to remote developer.

I tried using Team viewer VPN but it didn't let me run host services/GUI at remote system, however allocated private IPs were ping-able and shared directories were accessible.

Pl suggest me free VPN application & process to achieve remote access to Xampp files & GUI.

Thanks